# Aggregate Disks in Collectd or Graphite/Grafana

Tags: graphite, collectd, grafana

I have multiple nodes, each with multiple disks of the same size. I'd like for either

- collectd to report a single used/free metric that is the aggregate of these multiple disks
- construct a grafana query that combines multiple disks into a single %-free metric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a config example using the `aggregation` plugin that will compute global `df` statistics per `type-instance`, meaning one value per used, free and maybe others depending on your OS.

```
LoadPlugin aggregation

<Plugin aggregation>
  <Aggregation>
    Plugin "df"
    Type "percent_bytes"
    GroupBy "TypeInstance"
    CalculateMinimum true
    CalculateMaximum true
    CalculateAverage true
    SetPluginInstance "%{aggregation}"
    SetHost "global"
    SetPlugin "df"
  </Aggregation>
</Plugin>
```

As you can guess it will compute the average, min and max aggregations but you could also add the sum by using `CalculateSum`.